# Uncaught in promise (Foundation 6 Equalizer reinitializing after Typekit loads)

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation-6, typekit

Ok, I have this slight issue, I am **using JointsWP with WordPress**, and also loading **custom fonts from Typekit**. The fonts load with a slight delay and they keep flashing on the screen when swapping with fallback (issue for another time). I am trying to use Equalizer ([Documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html)) to equalize the heights on two columns.

**Because the fallback font is slightly smaller/lower, when TypeKit loads, the Equalizer has already loaded its heights and therefore it falls a bit short.** For instance the Height without Typekit is 320px and with Typekit fonts should be 325px. I have this callback function from Typekit, that should fire after the fonts have finished loading.

```
try {
        Typekit.load({
            active: function() {
                console.log("test")
                var elem = new Foundation.Equalizer(element);
                elem.applyHeight();         // Foundation 6
            }
        })
} catch(e) {}
```

However, I get an error

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: element is not defined(…)

I am not sure why that is. The script is loaded on the end of the page, after foundation javascript has already been loaded.

If anyone can clear this up for me, I would appreciate it dearly.
Thank you

Comment: It would help us help you if you could replicate the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You should use [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) not `catch`. It's an asynchronous error.

Comment: @Bergi thank you, that worked. I would never have figured it out myself.